# How to identify unique value instances and find the sum

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, lookup-tables

This question builds on my previous post regarding how to identify and output multiple instances of a found value. My previous post: 
[Array to lookup multiple columns and take another columns information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216587/array-to-lookup-multiple-columns-and-take-another-columns-information)

This question is slightly different, where what if I wanted to sum the values found in an array. I have presented an example below. The Table I2:J4 is the reference table which assigns a value to each Plant #. Cells B3:F9 are already filled in and are used to find the sum of one count of each instance in the row. Column A will show the solution of each row. The formula should allow the column to be populated automatically.

[image]

For example I have filled in the answer for the first three rows of Column A. In Row 3, we see that there is a Plant 1002B1, and 1003B1 so the answer is 200+300. We neglect any additional instances found of a Plant #. For example row 4 and 5 both have a sum of 100, regardless of how many instances of the same plant are found.

I found myself trying to use an Index but this would return True/False values and because of this you can't add the sum of the value. Unless you use the True/False to identify the location of the value in the reference table and use that to find that the sum, which I dont how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula

```
=SUM(IF(B2:F2<>"",IF(MATCH(B2:F2,B2:F2,0)=COLUMN(B2:F2)-MIN(COLUMN(B2:F2))+1,SUMIFS(J:J,I:I,B2:F2))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If one has the new Dynamic Array formula(currently only available to Office 365 Insiders) then it gets much simpler to get an array of unique entries:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(J:J,I:I,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(B2:F2))))
```

[image]

Comment: But this would add every instance of the value found, where I only want add it once if it is found. Even if you find the same Plant # X amount of times, it is only added once. You can see in A3 the solution is 500 because 1 x of 1002B1 is added to 1 x of 1003B1.

Comment: @ScottCraner Very nice! By the way, I am not part of the Insider program and I recently got the new array functions (on a VW - on my host machine, it's still not available). So I tried your second function and it works like a charm.

Comment: @MichaelWycisk it depends on you update cycle. Most are on a 6 month update schedule.